# How can I fill the background with a color scale in function of a lineal model?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scale, data-visualization

I'm analysing an example of datavis in "The Functional Art " of Alberto Cairo (I recomend to you)

In that book, there are this example

[image: http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/8327/snap1026.png]

And I try in R. In the bottom left graph (scatter plot)

I use the data from the book, and i calculate the efectives militaries in function of population with `lm(efect ~ pop)` and the budget in function of population + efect

And here is the question: How can I paint the background of the scatterplot with colorscale (gradient) where the color represent the value of BUDGET?

After that I want to put the points (population, efects) with the color of the budget.
In this way, I can compare the budget of the country with the stimated budget in function of population + efect

I know basic R, I have installed **ggplot2** and **scales** packages

I want a graph similar to

[image]

but with the correct colors.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that R is a substantially suboptimal choice if one intends to create nicely rendered graphics.

Comment: @Lucas - what leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: @Lucas, that is definitely not true. A graph like the OP showed is perfectly possible, in publication quality. I create all my graphs is R, and no journal has ever complained.

Comment: @Chase - Maybe it is just that by default they look tacky but you can make them better. Still, I am yet to see something that looks really good that has been made in R. Show me a nice R rendering and I may change my mind.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra - as a reviewer I would not complain about R graphs, but I would still be thinking "that looks a bit shit".

Comment: @Lucas - I see shitty graphics made from all sorts of software, R included. That does not mean that R does not have strong graphing capabilities...I'd wager there's a larger problem with the general population's inability to understand the fundamentals of good graphic design. As for something pretty in R, this seems to get decent reviews from the denizens of the world: http://revolution-computing.typepad.com/.a/6a010534b1db25970b0147e0ae51b2970b-popup.

Comment: @Chase I do like it, and some of the others are nice too :) It's this ggplot2 package right? It seems to fix a lot of the things I dislike about R plotting - I shall recommend it to my R using colleagues.

Comment: `ggplot2` is the best thing since sliced bread :). @Lucas what do you normally use for graphing? And why do you like this particular tool better?

Comment: @paulheimstra I guess I use matplotlib for most things, but often, it is determined by what interfaces with my other stuff most directly. For example, I graph a lot of simulations in realtime, but that is quite rough, low level, and not for publications (talks though). So, given that ggplot2 seems to be quite nice (I didn't realize this when I commented before) the only thing stopping me is that I tend not to use R, which is because of a general dislike of its opacity. The tool is part of a workflow and it has to be a damn good tool to change the choice of things that it depends on.

Answer (score 5):

To get the background you can use `geom_raster` to get the effect you want.  I'll use the same data set as suggested by @GeekOnAcid:

First get the data and fit a regression model:

```
crime = read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/crimeRatesByState2005.tsv", 
              header=TRUE, sep="\t")
 ##Fit the regression model
 m = lm(crime$burglary ~ crime$murder)
```

Next we create a grid for the background colour:

```
##Create a grid for the background colour
x = seq(1, 10, length.out=100)
y = seq(400, 1200, length.out=100)
z = expand.grid(x,y)
```

Now we need a distance measure for the gradient colour. I just used squared distance from the regression line:

```
z$grad = (z[,2] - (398.3 +  62.2*z[,1]))^2
```

Then plot:

```
require(ggplot2)    
ggplot(z) + geom_raster(aes(Var1, Var2, fill=grad)) + 
    geom_point(data=crime[1:15,], aes(murder, burglary, size=population),pch=1 ) + 
    geom_text(data=crime[1:15,], 
              aes(murder, burglary, label=state), 
              hjust=-0.2, size=4) + 
    scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10)) + 
    scale_fill_continuous(high="red", low="white", trans="sqrt") +
    xlab("Murder") + ylab("Burglary")  + 
    guides(size=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0))
```

To get:

[image]

Comment: +1, I love ggplot. Although I think the colors do not really add to the picture. Maybe plotting the residuals to the linear model would make for a better graph, which is easier to interpret if one is looking for countries which show anomalous behavior.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I agree, the background is a bit pointless and distracting.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started, take a look at [this tutorial by Nathan Yau](http://flowingdata.com/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts/), who shows how to create bubble chart with basic graphics in R. I only retrieved his solution to make it more relevant for your example.

```
#get some example data
crime <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/crimeRatesByState2005.tsv", 
                  header=TRUE, sep="\t")
#define the radius of circles
radius <- sqrt( crime$population/ pi )
#makes your plot, bg defines colour, inches scales circles
symbols(crime$murder[1:15], crime$burglary[1:15], circles=radius[1:15], 
        inches=0.5, bg=gray(0.9), xlab="Murder Rate", ylab="Burglary Rate")
#makes your labels, you can offset them by adding values to x and y arguments
text(crime$murder[1:15], crime$burglary[1:15], crime$state[1:15], cex=0.6)
```

[image]

The background thing will be tricky, but are you sure you really need it? Even with different colours it will look ugly...